# getting status of a sent message in JSMPP

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I am using JSMPP (Java implementation of SMPP) for sending SMS from my web application to SMS center. I have the following code to receive the delivery report of any sent SMS.

```
    public class MessageListenerImplementation implements MessageReceiverListener {
     public void onAcceptDeliverSm(DeliverSm deliverSm) throws ProcessRequestException {
        if (MessageType.SMSC_DEL_RECEIPT.containedIn(deliverSm.getEsmClass())) {
            try {
                DeliveryReceipt deliveryReceipt = deliverSm.getShortMessageAsDeliveryReceipt();
                 long id = Long.parseLong(deliveryReceipt.getId()) & 0xffffffff;
                  String messageId = Long.toString(id, 16).toUpperCase();
                   System.out.println("Delivery receipt for message '" + messageId + " ' from " + deliverSm.getSourceAddr() + " to " + deliverSm.getDestAddress() + " : " + deliveryReceipt);
            }catch (InvalidDeliveryReceiptException e) {
                System.err.println("Failed getting delivery receipt");
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I register the above listener for an SMS' delivery receipt and send it, it get the delivery receipt as follows

and the delivery receipt is as follows

```
id:5 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1312091213 done date:1312091213 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:Hello SMSC from ESME
```

Now I am wondering how to retrieve the sending status in some integer range that whether it is sent,failed or still pending so that I can use it to update my database accordingly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is DeliveryReceiptState enumaration in Jsmpp for the all delivery status codes. 
Try `deliveryReceipt.getFinalStatus().value()` which will you give you integer value to update in database.

You will get following integer values for status codes.

```
/**
     * DELIVERED
     */

    DELIVRD(1),
    /**
     * EXPIRED
     */
    EXPIRED(2),
    /**
     * DELETED
     */
    DELETED(3),
    /**
     * UNDELIVERABLE
     */
    UNDELIV(4),
    /**
     * ACCEPTED
     */
    ACCEPTD(5),
    /**
     * UNKNOWN
     */
    UNKNOWN(6),
    /**
     * REJECTED
     */
    REJECTD(7);
```

Comment: and what if I want to check later for an SMS status based on its id, is there any way to do this ?

Comment: can I use the stored id to check SMS status later ?

Comment: how ? id is of type integer, is there any method to which I pass this id and get the status of message..

Comment: Option1 :You need to check deliveryReceipt.getId() with stored id and for this you have to wait for deliveryReceipt .  
Option 2:Otherwise if you want to check the message status. Use QuerySm .